# How to pass mutiple value to another PHP page using checkbox?

Tags: php, arrays

DEMO.PHP

```
<form action = "test.php"  method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="'Peter'=>'35'">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="'Ben'=>'37'">I have a car <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST["vehicle"]))
{

$v = $_POST["vehicle"];

foreach($v as $x=>$x_value)
  {
  echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
  echo "<br>";
  }


}

?>
```

My $x didnt get Peter or Ben?

How can I get the key and value separately?

Comment: is it safe to do this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name your fields ending in `[]`, then PHP will construct a regular array from them.

Using `=>` in the *value* will have no special meaning.

If you want to specify the key names that PHP will parse the form data into, then you do so in the name:

```
name="vehicle[Peter]" value="35"
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you